# How to make parameter optional in Zend Framework Router

Tags: regex, zend-framework, router

I would like to know the .ini config file setup to make a route wherein the page number parameter is optional so that

```
http://news.mysite.com/national
http://news.mysite.com/national/1
```

point to the same page.

I have the code as follows

```
resources.router.routes.news_list.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
resources.router.routes.news_list.route = "([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([0-9\-]+)"
resources.router.routes.news_list.defaults.module = "news"
resources.router.routes.news_list.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.news_list.defaults.action = "category"
resources.router.routes.news_list.defaults.page = 1
resources.router.routes.news_list.map.1 = "categ"
resources.router.routes.news_list.map.2 = "page"
resources.router.routes.news_list.reverse = "%s/%s"
```

can some1 help me out with a solution to modify this code to make it work for both urls

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this without the regex route using:

```
routes.news_list.route = ":action/:page"
routes.news_list.defaults.module = "news"
routes.news_list.defaults.controller = "index"
routes.news_list.defaults.action = "category"
routes.news_list.defaults.page = 1
```

I assume that you want every request to go to the "news" module and the "index" controller. Only the action and the page are variable in the url.

Answer (score 3):

```
resources.router.routes.news_list.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
resources.router.routes.news_list.route = "([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?([0-9]+)?"
resources.router.routes.news_list.defaults.module = "news"
resources.router.routes.news_list.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.news_list.defaults.action = "category"
resources.router.routes.news_list.defaults.page = 1
resources.router.routes.news_list.map.1 = "categ"
resources.router.routes.news_list.map.2 = "page"
resources.router.routes.news_list.reverse = "%s/%d"
```

Something like this could work too in case you need to use Regex.