# Need to even further shorten easy urls using Zend Route

Tags: zend-framework, url-rewriting, url-routing

I might be asking a bit too much here but I would like to know how can I further shorten urls such that they look like there's not an inclusion of a controller.

eg: I want to shorten this:

```
www.mysite.com/users/Bob-123
```

to

```
www.mysite.com/Bob-123
```

or something like `www.mysite.com/bob-123-user`

Any ideas here? - I'm using the Zend framework here

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355891/how-to-make-parameter-optional-in-zend-framework-router/1356175#1356175

Answer (score 0):

You can do with the help of Zend Router .

Here you need to fetch the usernames and add routes to it. This way it will recognise which controller and action it needs to fetch.

```
$router = $this->_front->getRouter();

$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    ':username',
    array(
        'controller' => 'profile',
        'action'     => 'userinfo'
    )
);

$router->addRoute('user', $route);
```

An example taken from [zend manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.standard)

Answer (score 0):

In your application.ini you could do it using [Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.regex):

```
resources.router.routes.user.route = "(\w+)-(\d+)"
resources.router.routes.user.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex" 
resources.router.routes.user.defaults.controller = users
resources.router.routes.user.defaults.action = index
resources.router.routes.user.map.1 = username
resources.router.routes.user.map.2 = id
resources.router.routes.user.reverse = "/%s-%d"
```

You would need to specify your own action and controller. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh nice to know this way it will work. Does the other way has any issues ?

Comment: @Hari K T. Example from you answer will not allow for routes such as /bob-123.